# How to create a DTO in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, dto

1) I want to know what is the recommended way to create & return a DTO for an object which has 10 attributes and I only want to return 2 with my DTO object.

2) Should DTO's have their own namespace ? If yes, how do we organize them ? Each DTO inside a single class file or all DTO's inside a single class ?

Please provide me some sample code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DTOs are dumb objects composed of public getters/setters. I generally put them in a separate namespace called SomeProject.Dto.

```
public class CustomerDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LocationDto HomeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I generally try to keep the property names the same between the DTO and corresponding domain class, possibly with some flattening. For example, my Customer might have an Address object, but my DTO might have that flattened to:

```
public class CustomerDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HomeStreet { get; set; }
    public string HomeCity { get; set; }
    public string HomeProvince { get; set; }
    public string HomeCountry { get; set; }
    public string HomePostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

You can dramatically reduce the amount of repetitive mapping code of translating domain objects into DTOs by using Jimmy Bogard's AutoMapper.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the sample and explanation James =) Do you put each DTO inside a separate file or all DTOs inside a single file ? Don't you end with a a whole lot of new class files just for the DTOs alone ?

Comment: I put each DTO in separate files. They're all in a separate folder, which is easily collapsed and ignored. :)

Comment: @JamesKovacs would there be any real advantage to using structs with only member fields (no getters and setters) instead of classes?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very open ended. The answers are dependent on the scale of your application.

In general I create my DTO's or ViewModels in their own assembly. To get my DTO's I have some service layer take care of creating them based on my request.

If you want concrete examples take a look at some of the Asp.NET MVC examples at asp.net. While you may not be using MVC you can at least see how the ViewModels are created.

Comment: Thanks Brownman. My application scale is not that big. However, while creating a DTO, I end up creating seprate class files for even the basic DTO (returning only 1 attribute). What I want to know is how to reduce the class files and manage my DTO efficiently.I will have a look at MVC.

Comment: any specific link on Asp.NET MVC examples at asp.net ?

Comment: By going through the tutorials on asp.net you will get some good ideas. Here is an article that may also help, http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx.